# How to execute functions from a separate class?

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.7 from the Anaconda distro. I am trying to organize a complex data integration process into different classes and functions so I can better manage it.

As a simplified example, I have some part of my process in a file called `function_test.py`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class Perform:
    def work(self):
        test_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4), columns=['a','b','c','d'])
        print "really?"
        print test_df
```

I want to call and execute the above logic from `function_call.py` which is in the same directory:

```
import function_test

perform = function_test.Perform
perform.work
```

However, when I execute function_call.py I get the following message and nothing is printed.

```
UMD has deleted: function_test
```

How do I set this example up so function_test is imported and executed so test_df is available from within function_call.py?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, don't use old-style classes like so:

```
class Perform:
    pass
```

Use new-style classes:

```
class Perform(object):
    pass
```

Next, you should remember - `work` is a **method** of the class `Perform`. So you should instantiate it first:

```
perform = function_test.Perform()
perform.work()
```

Does it work now?

Comment: It does execute and prints from inside function_test.py. How do I make the test_df available in function_call.py? I added print test_df.dtypes and I get a 'test_df' is not defined error.

Comment: You can return it from function: `return test_df` and use: `test_df = perform.work()`

Answer (score 1):

add brackets.

```
perform = function_test.Perform()
perform.work()
```